# How do I prove that $6\mid 7^n - 1$ and/or $8\mid \big(\frac{7^n - 1}{6} + \frac{7^{n + 1} - 1}{6} - 1\big)?$

Tags: divisibility

> > Prove that: $$\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, \ 6\mid 7^n - 1$$

---

**My Attempt:**

I first let $n = 1$. $$6\mid 7^1 - 1$$ $$\implies 6\mid 6 \ \ \ \color{green}{\checkmark}$$ Now I let $n = 2$. $$6\mid 7^2 - 1$$ $$\implies 6\mid 48 \ \ \ \color{green}{\checkmark}$$ And now I let $n = 3$. $$6\mid 7^3 - 1$$ $$\implies 6\mid 342 \ \ \ \color{green}{\checkmark}$$ So now I try and find a pattern by dividing the $RHS$ by the $LHS$. $$6/6 = 1$$ $$48/6 = 8$$ $$342/6 = 57$$ There is a pattern on the $RHS$, where if you start from $1$, you multiply by $7$ and then add $1$. According to the pattern, this implies that $7^4 - 1 = 2400$ and thus $6\mid 2400$ which is true.

And it also seems that

> $$8\mid \bigg(\frac{7^n - 1}{6} + \frac{7^{n + 1} - 1}{6} - 1\bigg)$$

So now I have run into another problem and don't know how to prove *this*. Could somebody please help me? Surely there must be some special way of proving things like these, right? Hopefully it isn't too ugly to prove. I came up with this question by figuring it out, and I do believe that it *is* correct because it seems like it. I have tested for $n$ up to $100$ and it still looks true. Why is this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be proved with induction. First, show that it holds for $n=0$. Then, suppose it holds for some $n=k \in \mathbb N$ and show that if so, it must hold for $k+1$.

We have $7^0-1=0$, and $6\ |\ 0$.
Now, suppose $6\ | 7^k-1$ and given that, prove $6\ |\ 7^{k+1}-1$.

Comment: I find this answer most understandable $$\color{green}{\checkmark}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$7^n-1 = (6+1)^n-1= \sum_{i=0}^n \binom{n}{i} 6^i-1= 6 \sum_{i=1}^{n} \binom{n}{i} 6^{i-1} +1-1 \equiv 1-1 \equiv 0 \pmod{6}$$

For the second part, it would be sufficient to prove that $16 \mid 7^n-1+7^{n+1}-1-6$

$$1+7^{n+1}-1-6=7^n(7+1)-8 = 8(7^n-1)$$

Since $7^n-1$ is even, $\exists k \in \mathbb{Z} : 2k=(7^n-1)$. Then,

$$1+7^{n+1}-1-6=8(7^n-1)= 16k \equiv 0 \pmod{16}$$

Which makes your conjecture true.

Comment: I am sorry. I don't understand what the *big brackets* are (with $n$ and $i$). Could you please explain?

Comment: I used Newton's binomial. However, there is a simpler explanation. If we are mod 6, we can say $7=1$ because they give the same remainder when dividing by 6. So $7^n-1 \equiv 1^n-1 \pmod{6}$. @user477343

Comment: Ok. I did a little bit of research. $\text{mod}$ means "modulo" and finds the reminder a number after some division. Ok I'm getting the hang of it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest remains using *congruences*.

- $6\mid 7^n-1\iff 7^n\equiv 1\mod 6$.

This is obvious since $7\equiv 1\mod 6$, hence $7^n\equiv 1^n=1\mod 6$.

- Similarly, we have to prove $\;\dfrac{7^n-1}6+\dfrac{7^{n+1}-1}6\equiv 1\mod8$.

Now, $\begin{aligned}\dfrac{7^n-1}6&=\dfrac{7^n-1}{7-1}=7^{n-1}+7^{n-2}+\dots+7+1\\&\equiv (-1)^{n-1}+(-1)^{n-2}+\dots-1+1\equiv\begin{cases}0&\text{if }n\;\text{is even,}\\1&\text{if }n\;\text{is odd.}\end{cases}\end{aligned}$

Thus exactly one of $\;\dfrac{7^n-1}6$ and $\;\dfrac{7^{n+1}-1}6$ is congruent to $1$ mod. $8$, the other is congruent to $0$. The result follows.

Answer (score 1):

$$►7^n=(6+1)^n=6M+1\Rightarrow7^n-1=6M$$

$$►►\big(\frac{7^n - 1}{6} + \frac{7^{n + 1} - 1}{6} - 1\big)=\frac{7^n(1+7)-2}{6}-1=\frac{7^n\cdot8-8}{6}=8\left(\frac{7^n-1}{6}\right)=8M$$

Comment: Very good answer. In fact, I am going to give you *all* a $+1$