# How can I prove that $3| (4^n - 1)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

How can I prove that $3| (4^n - 1)$ or 3 divides $4^n - 1$?

I have started it by induction, so the basis works and I assumed the induction hypothesis $3| (4^n - 1)$ but do not know how to use it to simplify  $3| (4^{(n + 1)} - 1)$. could anyone help me to show this?

Comment: $4^n-1=(4-1)(4^{n-1}+4^{n-2}+...+4+1)$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I prove that $6\mid 7^n - 1$ and/or $8\mid \big(\frac{7^n - 1}{6} + \frac{7^{n + 1} - 1}{6} - 1\big)?$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2442370/how-do-i-prove-that-6-mid-7n-1-and-or-8-mid-big-frac7n-16-frac)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To prove by that the next term in the sequence $4^{n+1}-1$ is also divisible by $3$, it makes sense to prove that the *difference* is divisible by $3$. The difference between two consecutive terms is
$$(4^{n+1}-1)-(4^n-1)=4^{n+1}-4^n=4^n(4-1).$$

Answer (score 1):

Use the identity $q^{n+1}-1 = (1+q+\ldots+q^n)(q-1)$.

For $q=4$, we get $4^{n+1}-1 = a\cdot (4-1)=3a$ for some number $a$.

Answer (score 1):

To prove by induction you can do this:
$$ 4^{n+1}-1=4^{n+1}-4+4-1=4(4^n-1)+3.$$
Hence, $3\lvert 4^{n+1}-1$.

Answer (score 1):

$n=0$√, let $n \ge 1$.

$(3+1)^n -1= $

$\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}3^{n-k}1^k-1=$

$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{n}{k}3^{n-k} +1-1$;

The binomial expression is divisible by $3$.

Answer (score 0):

$$4=3+1$$ So: $$4^n-1=(3+1)^n-1$$ Which by FOIL, has all but one term of the power expansion divisible by 3, leaving $$1^n=1$$  and $$1-1=0$$ This shows regardless of natural number n,  $$3\mid 4^n-1$$